# Music not playing when use Deezer SDK android sample demo

Tags: android, sdk, deezer

I am using the Deezer SDK android sample demo(0.10.16) and I try to play songs,but it doesn't play anything,the music just doesn't start but warning recvfrom  failed:ECONNRESET(Connection reset by peer) or URL could not be resolved on Deezer servers Received HTTP response code.I found out that the problem only  occurred with TV device,but it can play on emulators.I still don't know why?

Comment: The Deezer SDK for Android has not been tested yet on Android TV, and so these devices aren't supported yet.

Comment: Any news for the deezer sdk on Android TV ?